# java schedule a callable at pseudo 'fixed' rate (bell curve distribution for example)

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, threadpool, callable

Currently I have a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor which can execute a callable at a fixed rate.

```
scheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(callable, delay, waitNano, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
```

My team wants to add some randomess into the waitNano. Currently it is 1000. But we want the wait second to be 900, 1100, 800, 1200, for example. The average wait time is still 1000 but the wait second is randomly distributed, (for example like a Bell curve).

I am wondering is this functionality already in java? 
If I have to write my own "scheduler" which has this random-waiting behavior, what do you guys suggest?

Thanks a lot!

Erben

Comment: AFAIK, it's not built into the standard library. It's possible that there is a third party library somewhere that can do this for you, but I don't know of it. (You might want to look at http://quartz-scheduler.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Invoke another `Runnable` at *fixed* schedules (for example 10 min) and let it configure random scheduler's next execution randomly still managing randomness

using [`schedule();`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule-java.util.concurrent.Callable-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)

**For example**: first column shows execution of fixed scheduler which determines when to execute managed random scheduler

```
0    1
5    7
10   11
15   18
```

Comment: The semantic is not quite the same though, let's say we want interval as 500 nano second but with  +/- 350 jitter. 
By this approach, we would have fixed schedule every 150 nano second, and inside it, it will schedule another random task from [0, 700] nano second delay to make sure mean and variance are the same. [500 - 350, 500 + 350] = [150, 150 + 700]
But by doing this, it is possible the second schedule happen before the first schedule. For example, the first one pick 600, the second one pick 200, which will happen at 150+200=350 nano second before 600.